# determine last child in row using susy2

Tags: susy-sass

I'm using susy to create a responsive grid and I was wondering if I have a set of columns like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-4">Col 1</div>
  <div class="col-4">Col 2</div>
  <div class="col-4">Col 3</div>
</div>
```

how do I get susy to determine the last child?

I also noticed whenever I have this set up the margin-right causes them to be to wide for the container and they stack.

I tried to use last-flow: to, and it doesn't seem to be responding either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [the `span` mixin](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#row-edges), you can specify `first` or `last` and Susy will remove the extra gutter where relevant (it depends on your "gutter-position" setting).

All it really does is set `margin-left` or `margin-right` to `0`, so of course there are lots of ways to deal with extra gutters depending on how you're using Susy. Without seeing your Sass and Susy config & usage, it's hard to say exactly what you should do.

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing.